# Check if a string is all numbers and 10 chars long

Tags: php

Just looking for a quick way using PHP to check if a string is all numbers and 10 numbers long.

eg:

4343434345 - this would be accepted (10 chars all digits)

343434344 - this wouldn't (9 chars)

sdfefsefsdf - this wouldn't.

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('~^\d{10}$~', $str)) { ... }
```

or

```
if (ctype_digit($str) && strlen($str) == 10) { ... }
```

Answer (score 4):

ex:-

```
if(preg_match('/^\d{10}$/', $str))
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
```